# css backgrounds not deploying

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, github-pages

I'm attempting to deploy my react project to GH-pages using HashRouter, which makes the url: https://foo.github.io/foo-site/#/ Everything is surprisingly working well except for my css background images. They work locally, but in deployment I just get 404s.

My folder structure is..

```
App/
|--build/
|--public/
|  |--images/
|  |  |--background.jpg
|--src
|  |--Components.js
|  |--style.css
|--package.json
|--yarn.lock
```

the path for the css background images look like

```
foo {
   background-image(/images/background.jpg)
}
```

what would cause this to work on my local react server, but not in deployment?

Comment: When deployed are your images at: `https://foo.github.io/foo-site/images/background.jpg`?

Comment: Try to remove the first forward slash, like: background-image('images/background.jpg');

Comment: Yes, they're trying to render at https://foo.github.io/foo-site/images/background.jpg, so I'm assuming it needs the # before the /images/ ? When I remove the forward slash before images, it breaks on my react server.

Comment: your css image paths are absolute.  they need to be `/foo-site/images/background.jpg`

Comment: Ok, without the # ?

Comment: would I have to switch back and forth from localhost:300//images/background.jpg to /foo-site/images/background.jpg ?

Answer (score 1):

moving my images/ folder into my src/ folder did the trick. I then changed the background images paths to

```
foo {
   /*background-image: url(/images/background.jpg)*/
   background-image: url(images/background.jpg) 
}
```